# Select dynamic data from column of data

Tags: performance, excel, vba

Good day,  I have two problems to resiolve.

I have two columns, one on the left is a column of speed readings over a 7 days where the readings are taken dynamically for each vehicle passing.  to the right of this column  is the date and time of the speed reading.  The readings need to be collated into hourly readings , e.g. 1700hrs to 1800hrs etc.  I have managed to suss this using countifs, however because the data is dynamic, i need to be able to have the excel vba do this.  Then knowing the range of data for each hourly time slice, i need to apply the stats function , = percentile( x, 0.85) to get the 85th percentile of the speed measurments over the hour period.

Can anybody help with this to get it into a vba format?

I have created a link to the file in question below

[SpeedDataCalculations](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b2up2ejmpidkzaz/DateTimeSpeedData.xlsx)

Thanks in advance

Colin

Comment: I do not understand why the countif can't do the job

Comment: If it's always the previous seven days, you should be able to have a static-sized table that calculates the values of the 168 one-hour slices and then do your percentile on those slices. At any rate, I don't think you need VBA.

Comment: but the number of speed data reading will change and this is why i need to know the cell range to claculate the percentile

Comment: I can work on this later if nobody gets back to you.

Answer (score 0):

This was done with Excel 2010 and assumes your data is in a table. I set it up like this:

[image]

The table has your time and speed entries.

The analysis is done using the "Time Increments" and "Percentile" columns. I made an assumption that your increments go up to midnight of yesterday, e.g., 6/25/2013 00:00 in this case. I made these increments dynamic by putting this formula in `D2`:

`=INT(NOW())-1`

Then in cell `D3` I put this formula and copied it down to `D169` giving one week's worth of hourly increments:

`=D2-(1/24)`

Finally in Column E, I entered this [array formula](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

`=PERCENTILE(
IF((Table1[Time]<=D2)*(Table1[Time]>D3),Table1[Speed],""),
0.85)`

This says to get the 85th percentile for all speeds in the table where the time is less than or equal to the time in the same row of Column D, and greater than the time one cell down.